# PATCH endpoint using ASP.NET Core Web API with Entity Framework for many-to-many entity relations

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement a `PATCH` endpoint for a `Note` entity related to a `Tag` entity by a many-to-many relation. The remove operation for removing a `Tag` from a list of `Tags` in a `Note` is throwing an error.

I have these `Note` and `Tag` model classes:

```
public class Note
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Tag>? Tags { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChangedDate { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public List<Note>? Notes { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Both these model classes are related by a many-to-many relation using a join table configured with Fluent API. The `DbContext` is provided below

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
}

public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Note>()
                .HasMany(n => n.Tags)
                .WithMany(t => t.Notes)
                .UsingEntity(j => j
                .ToTable("NoteTag")
                .HasData
                (
                    new {NotesID = 1, TagsTagID = 1},
                    new {NotesID = 2, TagsTagID = 2}
                ));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().HasData
            (
            new Tag
            {
                TagID= 1,
                TagName="testTag1",
                CreatedDate= DateTime.Now
            },
            new Tag
            {
                TagID= 2,
                TagName = "testTag2",
                CreatedDate= DateTime.Now
            }
            );
    modelBuilder.Entity<Note>().HasData
            (
            new Note
            {
                ID= 1,
                Title="testTitle1",
                Description="testDescription1",
                Deleted=false,
                CreatedDate= DateTime.Now,
                ChangedDate= DateTime.Now,
            },
            new Note
            {
                ID = 2,
                Title = "testTitle2",
                Description = "testDescription2",
                Deleted = false,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                ChangedDate = DateTime.Now,
            }
            );
}
```

I am trying to create a `PATCH` endpoint to update `Note` as below

```
[HttpPatch("{id:int}", Name = "UpdateNote")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public IActionResult UpdateNote(int id, JsonPatchDocument<Note> patchNoteDTO)
    {
        if (id == 0 || patchNoteDTO == null)
            return BadRequest();
        var note = _db.Notes.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
        if (note == null)
            return NotFound();
        patchNoteDTO.ApplyTo(note, ModelState);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        note.ChangedDate = DateTime.Now;
        _db.Update(note);
        _db.SaveChanges();
        return NoContent();
    }
```

All the operations work but when I try to remove a Tag from the list of Tags in Note by providing an index in the path of the patch document, I get the following error
([Swagger UI Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MANMF.png)).
([Patch document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AC82p.png)).
Could anyone suggest a solution? I'm surely missing something but can't seem to identify it. Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.Include` , change your code like below:

```
  var note = _db.Notes.Include(x=>x.Tags).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
```

Read [Eager Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#eager-loading) to know more.

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works but the corresponding entry in the NoteTag (Join) table is not deleted. Any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Additionally, trying to update any other property like the title throws an error as SaveChanges() is trying to insert a duplicate record in NoteTag

Comment: @TanmayManjunath If you use `return new ObjectResult(note);` , you will see, it remove tags from the Note, but as you said  the corresponding entry in the NoteTag (Join) table is not deleted, because we don't do action to NoteTag (Join) table , though we  do `_db.Update(note);` , but I think you want that. I am very sorry I cannot know how to fix it. Maybe you can create a new post to describe the problem about the corresponding entry in NoteTag (Join) table is not deleted. So that more peple can see it and help us to solve it.